# Creating and querying Geopoint in JanusGraph using Gremlin JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I can't find a way to create a vertex that holds a Geopoint using the gremlin JavaScript client (3.4.2).

The schema defined for the property is the following:

```
geopoint=mgmt.makePropertyKey('geopoint').dataType(Geoshape.class).cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
```

Reading the documentation from JanusGraph I should be able to do something like this, both for querying and creating:

```
g.addV('location').property('geopoint', Geoshape.point(45.944, 18.485));
```

The problem is that I cannot find that 'Geoshape' type anywhere using the gremlin client. I've also tried to use as property value a GeoJSON and an object like '{lat: 45.848, lng: 16.487}' but neither of them worked.

Which is the way to create and query a Geoshape.point for JanusGraph using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Geoshape` is a feature of JanusGraph, TinkerPop (and thus Gremlin) do not natively support such a feature. You would have to rely on JanusGraph to provide that functionality and as of right now I don't think that they provide a Javascript extension for doing so. Just as an example though, you can see that such support is provided in their [.NET library](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet/blob/1f1550106570a43746b1d96e785c7615fdb5ecd6/src/JanusGraph.Net/Geoshapes/Geoshape.cs).

Your only workaround at this time for doing `Geoshape` based queries in Javascript is to [submit scripts](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_submitting_scripts_4) to Gremlin Server which gives you access to the `Geoshape` Java class on the server.

Comment: Hello again Stephen, thank you also for this answer. I indeed realized what you're telling me the day after i posted the question. though I also found out, thanks to a Gremlin guide book by Kelvin Lawrence, that I can do most traversal that have to do with geopoint using a simple vertex with lng and lat properties as doubles. Maybe I should answer my question and reference what found.

Answer (score 1):

As from @stephen mallette answer, this cannot be done using the gremlin client.
But I found out a good workaround thanks to this [book by Kelvin Lawrence](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.adoc#latlonmanual).